# angular Sorting numbers by toggle function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, toggle

So what i'm trying to do here is to sort the numbers "2", "20", "3", "30", "21"
in the correct order from ascending to descending sort of like a toggle function.

However It seems as it orders from 
30
3
21
20
2
and when clicking the function button again:
2
20
21
3
30
Sort

Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  isAscendic = true
   fruits: any = ["2", "20", "3", "30", "21", ];





 <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">{{fruit}}
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button (click)="send()">Sort </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with **numbers**, not strings. You're comparing strings instead, so you first need to cast them to numbers:

```
if (+a1 < +a2) {
  //^---- note the + on both a1 and a2.
    return 1;
}
if (+a1 > +a2) {
    return -1;
}
```

Updated (working) stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzfjd7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

---

**Another possible approach** is to map the items first, and use the mapped array instead.

```
  protected get numericFruits() {
    return this.fruits.map(i => Number(i));
  }
```

Then use `numericFruits` instead of `fruits`.

Full code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  isAscendic = true
   fruits: any = ["2", "20", "3", "30", "21", ];

   send(){
     this.isAscendic?this.ascendic():this.descendic()
   }

  protected get numericFruits() {
    return this.fruits.map(i => Number(i));
  }

  ascendic(){
    this.isAscendic = false;
     this.fruits = this.numericFruits.sort((a1,a2) => {
        if (a1 < a2) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a1 > a2) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
  }

  descendic(){
    this.isAscendic = true
  this.fruits = this.numericFruits.sort((a1,a2) => {
    if (a1 > a2) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a1 < a2) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
  }
}
```

Working stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5ox91?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

> ## Issue

You are comparing the string value with comparator `>` and `<`. This will will have different for string value.

> ## Fix

It has very simple just convert the string value to number by appending `+` operator.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  isAscendic = true
   fruits: any = ["2", "20", "3", "30", "21", ];

   send(){
     this.isAscendic?this.ascendic():this.descendic()
   }

  ascendic(){
    this.isAscendic = false;
     this.fruits = this.fruits.sort((a1,a2) => {
    if (+a1 < +a2) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (+a1 > +a2) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
  }

  descendic(){
    this.isAscendic = true
  this.fruits = this.fruits.sort((a1,a2) => {
    if (+a1 > +a2) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (+a1 < +a2) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
  }

  de
}
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6fwmpn

Comment: Very cool thank you, hm what would happen if a number would be set to null?

Comment: it will convert to `NaN` and eventually all condition will be `false`. It will not throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

While using strings, you could convert the values to a number and take the delta as result for sorting.

```
this.fruits = this.fruits.sort((a, b) => +a - +b); // asc
this.fruits = this.fruits.sort((a, b) => +b - +a); // desc
```